# Getting folder application runs from in Mojolicious Lite

Tags: perl, mojolicious-lite

I want to be able to run my Mojolicious Lite app on shared hosting either from root (`www.domain.com/`) or subfolder (`www.domain.com/misc/mymojoapp/`).
The app's .pl file always goes to cgi-bin folder of the domain (`www.domain.com/cgi-bin/myapp.pl`) and I want to use mod_rewrite rules in `.htaccess` to point to the app. Images/css/js files would be under `www.domain.com/misc/mymojoapp/support`.

But I cannot figure out how I reliably get `misc/mymojoapp/` part of the path so I can pass it into templates. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

```
# set apache handler to treat your specified script name(s) as a CGI program
Options +ExecCGI
<Files ~ "(mymojoapp)$">
  SetHandler cgi-script
</Files>
# rewrite any requests into the appRewriteEngine onRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} 
!-fRewriteRule ^(.*)$ misc/mymojoapp/$1 [L]
```

and in your App

```
# set env variable to use root for pretty URLs

$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} = '/';
```

Change the above setting for pretty URL

Comment: I cannot change server settings on shared hosting - is `Options +ExecCGI` set in htaccess? I do have that re-write rule in my `.htaccess`, and I tried `$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} = '/';` - that did not change anything.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Dreamhost and this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mojolicious/bxdlP-MKuIQ

Comment: Yes add the first part in `.htaccess`